# Frame generation for video in python

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library, sequence, wand, pycairo

I am using the **Wand** library to generate images. Next, I create a video from these frames. Each frame represents a set of animated objects, text, shapes, embedded images. To create a one-minute sequence, my machine takes about three minutes of working time. How can i use resources more efficiently and speed up execution using python?

```
from wand.color import Color
from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color
from wand.font import Font
from pathlib import Path


resolution = "1080, 1920".split(",")
duration = "2"
framerate = "24"
width, height = int(resolution[0]), int(resolution[1])
amount = int(duration) * int(framerate)

temp_dir = Path().absolute() / "generator" / "temp_2"
font_path = "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf"
src_path = Path().absolute() / "generator" / "src"


def framegen(width, height, amount) -> list:

    frames = []
    x_position = int(width/2)
    y_position = int(height/2)
    font_size = 80
    text = "Hello world!"

    background_pattern = Image(filename=src_path / "pattern.png")

    for i in range(amount+1):
        frames.append(Image(width=width, height=height,
                      background=Color("white")))
        with Drawing() as draw:
            # Draw pattern image
            draw.composite(operator='over', left=0, top=0, width=background_pattern.width,
                           height=background_pattern.height, image=background_pattern)

            draw.fill_color = Color("blue")
            draw.rectangle(left=x_position-100, top=y_position -
                           100, right=x_position+100, bottom=y_position+100)

            draw.font = font_path
            draw.font_size = font_size
            draw.fill_color = Color("black")
            draw.text_alignment = "center"
            draw.text(x_position, y_position, text)

            draw(frames[i])

            background_pattern.rotate(1)
            y_position -= 5
            font_size += 2

    return frames


def save_frames(frames, temp_dir):
    paths = []
    for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
        frame.save(filename=f"{temp_dir}/frame_{i}.png")
        paths.append(f"{temp_dir}/frame_{i}.png")
    return paths

if __name__ == "__main__":
    frames = framegen(width, height, amount)
    save_frames(frames, temp_dir)
```

Comment: Please show your minimum working example. Thank you.

Comment: please take the [tour], then review [ask] and [help/on-topic]. giving commands like "Show an example..." to people that are willing to give you free help is kinda rude. show your research, which is expected in every question. show your own attempt ([mre]), which is also expected. this is a site for programming issues, not for wish fulfillment.

Comment: try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour -- first thing: `resolution = "1080, 1920".split(",")` is silly. write `width, height = 1920, 1080` and use

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Or make it a tuple, `resolution = (1080, 1920)`

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:pycairo], but you don't appear to be using it. Why the tag?

Comment: @Mast the code uses those values individually, and it already has those variables. I find them named individually to be cleaner than picking a tuple apart again with `[0]` and such

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes, making it a tuple only makes sense if coordinates in (x, y) format are used more often. For this small example, it would not be worth making an unpack wrapper. However, if the program grows and coordinates are use more often (it already is in some of the `draw` calls), it could make sense and being aware of the possibility doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Mast, thanks for the helpful comments. It is not so important for me which library will be used to draw frames. I'm looking for something that will give more performance.